# List of functions in a library written in php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm new on vscode. I previously used Eclipse but I decided to move to vscode.

I have a problem with my source code : in a php file, I have a list of functions. The whole file has 1839 lines with about 50 functions.

Is there a way to have a table of content made with these functions names, and then clicking on it, going right away in the portion of code of the function ?

Comment: You just need to install the PHP code intellisense extension of you choice. I think all the major ones provide that feature. If unsure, just click "PHP" in the Welcome Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a php question but vscode, you should try PHP Intellisense plugin it will give you outline of php file in sidebar. With it installed you can also press ctrl+p and typing @ will also show you list of symbols.
 Here's link [PHP Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense)